# How to make the background fixed but the listview scrollable?

Tags: android, listview, background-image, fixed, scrollable

I almost finished my app and now I'm doing my final touches. I've made my listview transparent and I have set a background and it's horrible. How can I make my image fixed and only the listview scrollable?

Here is my XML. I have a lot of these kinds of lists.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:textSize="10pt" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: ListView is scrollable by default, why do you need scrolling for it..?

Comment: oh, i didn't knew this, anyway, the app is working as i want, but my problem is with the background

Comment: amazing, all i needed to do was to delete the scroll! THX!